# Adding Plugin Attribute in MVC5 htmlAttributes

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, mask

Hi Im new to MVC5 and I just want to ask how can I add the attribute for my Editor so i can add phone mask in it

Heres the code

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

and heres the attribute that i want to add

```
data-mask="(999) 999-9999"
```

I tried it in a simple input and it works

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="Phone">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_mask = "(999) 999-9999" } }` (underscore will be converted to hyphen by razor engine)

Comment: @StephenMuecke what is `data_mask`? just curious.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, A attribute used by a jquery plugin I assume,  but I don't which one :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just tried data_mask and it doesn't work.

Comment: @CodingYoshi data-mask is a plugin by jasny

Comment: What does not work? - It will add `data-mask="(999) 999-9999"` assuming your using MVC-5.1+. Otherwise use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", data_mask = "(999) 999-9999", placeholder = "Phone" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you !  It is that i didnt include the package in global startapp

Answer (score 0):

```
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_mask = "(999) 999-9999" } }
```

(underscore will be converted to hyphen by razor engine)

great answer by  user3559349